# Java JMS MessageListener onMessage running on some PCs but not others

Tags: java, jboss, jms, publish-subscribe

I am seeking insights into this strange problem we are having with a Java software application.  The application is downloaded from a web site and communicates
with a server on the internet using a JMS/JBOSS in a publish/subscribe model.  At a high level, the problem is that on many of our Windows 7 PCs (64-Bit Win7 OS with JRE 1.7.0_51-b13 32 bit), the client application does not receive the messages sent from the server.  The onMessage() method appears to not get invoked.

The frustrating bit is that on some of our PCs (which were deployed using Ghost hard drive image so theoretically should have identical configurations), the application does receive the messages - We can see onMessage() method is working as expected.

I am able to examine the TCP/IP traffic coming in to the PC and I can see the messages arriving from the server to the client's TCP/IP stack. But somehow there is something keeping the messages from triggering the Java onMessage handler.

Another really strange twist is that if we leave the client application running for maybe 20 minutes, suddenly it starts to receive messages (that is the onMessage() method gets triggered). Again we know it is getting messages all along from looking at the TCP/IP traffic.

The basic outline of the code we are using is shown below. I think it pretty much follows the example here[1](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/docs/Server_Configuration_Guide/4/html/JMS_Examples-A_Pub_Sub_Example.html) and has most of the similar elements. Any suggestions for further debugging or exploration would be appreciated.

```
public class MyPubSub {
         private static final String CONN_FACTORY_QUEUE = "jms/RemoteConnectionFactory";
         private static final String QUEUE_A = "jms/queue/QueueA";
         private static final String CONN_FACTORY_TOPIC = "jms/RemoteConnectionFactory";
         private static final String USERNAME = "xyz";
         private static final String PWD = "xyz123";

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
         String hostURL = "some_host_string_thing_here";
         String remotingURL = "remote://"+hostURL+":4447";  

         // Establish context
         Context ctx;
         QueueConnectionFactory qcf = null;
         Properties p = new Properties();
         p.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");
         p.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, remotingURL);
         p.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, USERNAME);
         p.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, PWD);
         ctx = new InitialContext(p);

         // Set up Queue

         QueueConnectionFactory qcf = null;
         QueueConnection qconn = null;
         QueueSession qsession = null;
         Queue queueA = null;
         QueueReceiver qrecv = null;

         qcf = (QueueConnectionFactory)ctx.lookup(CONN_FACTORY_QUEUE);
         qconn = qcf.createQueueConnection(USERNAME, PWD);
         qsession = qconn.createQueueSession(false, QueueSession.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
         messageProducer = qsession.createProducer(queueA);

         // Set up Topic
         TopicConnectionFactory tcf;
         TopicConnection connA = null;
         TopicSession sessionA = null;
         Topic topicA = null;  
         TopicSubscriber recvA;

         tcf = (TopicConnectionFactory)ctx.lookup(CONN_FACTORY_TOPIC);
         topicA = (Topic)ctx.lookup(TOPICA);
         connA = tcf.createTopicConnection(USERNAME, PWD);
         connA.setExceptionListener(new ExceptionListenerImpl());
         sessionA = connA.createTopicSession(false, TopicSession.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
         messageProducerA = sessionA.createProducer(getJmsDestination(TOPICA));
         recvA = sessionA.createSubscriber(topicA);
         // Associate the MessageListener ExListenerA()
         recvA.setMessageListener(new ExListenerA());
         // Start
         connA.start();
}

public class ExListenerA implements MessageListener {
       public void onMessage(Message msg) {
           TextMessage oo = (TextMessage) msg;
           System.out.println("Got message" + oo.getText());
      }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After setting the message listener the connection is not started. That could have caused the problem.

Comment: I edited the example - we do call connA.start(); (I missed it when I copied and pasted in the code the first time) - Thanks